# sqlite.swift linked library or also embedded?

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I manually installed the SQLite.swift library in my project, following [the instructions in the documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#manual). But there the library will only be linked. It's running fine in the emulator and I am able to upload it to iTunes connect. When I want to run it directly on my iPad from Xcode I need to embed the library, too. My question is, if for publishing the app in iTunes connect and so to be able to run it on a device do I have to embed the library, too? It seems strange to me, because in the documentation it is written that it's enough to link the library.

Comment: I add it to my project folder and made a reference to it. My question is if i have also to embed the library when i want to publish the app because if i want to ran the app on a real device i have to embedd it too. I don't know if when i archive my project the sqlite.swift library will included automatically or i have first embedd it.

Comment: This doesn't completely answer your question but see this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783275/adding-an-xcode-subproject-shouldnt-all-the-source-files-get-copied